# Concurrent updates on a single staging table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, concurrency, threadpool, updates

I am developing a service application (VB.NET) which pulls information from a source and imports it to a SQL Server database

The process can involve one or more “batches” of information at a time (the number and size of batches in any given “run” is arbitrary based on a queue maintained elsewhere)

Each batch is assigned an identifier (BatchID) so that the set of records in the staging table which belong to that batch can be easily identified

The ETL process for each batch is sequential in nature; the raw data is bulk inserted to a staging table and then a series of stored procedures perform updates on a number of columns until the data is ready for import

These stored procedures are called in sequence by the service and are generally simple UPDATE commands

Each SP takes the BatchID as an input parameter and specifies this as the criteria for inclusion in each UPDATE, á la :

```sql
UPDATE dbo.stgTable
SET FieldOne = (CASE
                    WHEN S.[FieldOne] IS NULL
                        THEN T1.FieldOne
                    ELSE
                        S.[FieldOne]
                END
                )
, FieldTwo =   (CASE
                    WHEN S.[FieldTwo] IS NULL
                        THEN T2.FieldTwo
                    ELSE
                        S.[FieldTwo]
                END
                )
FROM dbo.stgTable AS S
LEFT JOIN dbo.someTable T1 ON S.[SomeField] = T1.[SomeField]
LEFT JOIN dbo.someOtherTable T2 ON S.[SomeOtherField] = T2.[SomeOtherField]
WHERE S.BatchID = @BatchID
```

Some of the SP’s also refer to functions (both scalar and table-valued) and all incorporate a TRY / CATCH structure so I can tell from the output parameters if a particular SP has failed

The final SP is a MERGE operation to move the enriched data from the staging table into the production table (again, specific to the provided BatchID)

I would like to thread this process in the service so that a large batch doesn’t hold up smaller batches in the same run

I figured there should be no issue with this as no thread could ever attempt to process records in the staging table that could be targeted by another thread (no race conditions)

However, I’ve noticed that, when I do thread the process, arbitrary steps on arbitrary batches seem to fail (but no error is recorded from the output of the SP)

The failures are inconsistent; e.g. sometimes batches 2, 3 & 5 will fail (on SP’s 3, 5 & 7 respectively), other times it will be different batches, each at different steps in the sequence

When I import the batches sequentially, they all import perfectly fine – always!

I can’t figure out if this is an issue on the service side (VB.NET) – e.g. is each thread opening an independent connection to the DB or could they be sharing the same one (I’ve set it up that each one *should* be independent…)

Or if the issue is on the SQL Server side – e.g. is it not feasible for concurrent SP calls to manipulate data on the same table, even though, as described above, no thread/batch will ever touch records belonging to another thread/batch

(On this point – I tried using CTE’s to create subsets of data from the staging table based on the BatchID and apply the UPDATE’s to those instead but the exact same behaviour occurred)

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
             SELECT *
             FROM dbo.stgTable
             WHERE BatchID = @BatchID
            )
UPDATE CTE...
```

Or maybe the problem is that multiple SP’s are calling the same function at the same time and that is why one or more of them are failing (I don’t see why that would be a problem though?)

Any suggestions would be very gratefully received – I’ve been playing around with this all week and I can’t for the life of me determine precisely what the problem might be!

### Update to include sample service code

This is the code in the service class where the threading is initiated

```vb
For Each ItemInScope In ScopedItems
    With ItemInScope 
        _batches(_batchCount) = New Batch(.Parameter1, .Parameter2, .ParameterX)
        With _batches(_batchCount)
            If .Initiate() Then
                _doneEvents(_batchCount) = New ManualResetEvent(False)
                Dim _batchWriter = New BatchWriter(_batches(_batchCount), _doneEvents(_batchCount))
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf _batchWriter.ThreadPoolCallBack, _batchCount)
            Else
                _doneEvents(_batchCount) = New ManualResetEvent(True)
            End If
        End With
    End With
    _batchCount += 1
Next

WaitHandle.WaitAll(_doneEvents)
```

Here is the BatchWriter class

```vb
Public Class BatchWriter

    Private _batch As Batch
    Private _doneEvent As ManualResetEvent

    Public Sub New(ByRef batch As Batch, ByVal doneEvent As ManualResetEvent)
        _batch = batch
        _doneEvent = doneEvent
    End Sub

    Public Sub ThreadPoolCallBack(ByVal threadContext As Object)
        Dim threadIndex As Integer = CType(threadContext, Integer)
        With _batch
            If .PrepareBatch() Then
                If .WriteTextOutput() Then
                    .ProcessBatch()
                End If
            End If
        End With
        _doneEvent.Set()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The PrepareBatch and WriteTextOutput functions of the Batch class are entirely contained within the service application - it is only the ProcessBatch function where the service starts to interact with the database (via Entity Framework)

Here is that function

```vb
Public Sub ProcessScan()
    ' Confirm that a file is ready for import
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(_filePath) Then
        Dim dbModel As New DatabaseModel
        With dbModel
            ' Pass the batch to the staging table in the database
            If .StageBatch(_batchID, _filePath) Then
                ' First update (results recorded for event log)
                If .UpdateOne(_batchID) Then
                    _stepOneUpdates = .RetUpdates.Value
                    ' Second update (results recorded for event log)
                    If .UpdateTwo(_batchID) Then
                        _stepTwoUpdates = .RetUpdates.Value
                        ' Third update (results recorded for event log)
                        If .UpdateThree(_batchID) Then
                            _stepThreeUpdates = .RetUpdates.Value

                            ....
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please read [ask] and then provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Enigmativity - I'm not sure how I can provide an example that is both minimal and complete though? To achieve completeness, I'd have to provide the threaded service code (not minimal) and all my SQL procedures (also not minimal) and I didn't want to overload the thread with code (most of which I wouldn't be allowed to share anyway) I guess I was hoping for a high-level suggestion based on the high-level information provided above. Is that not permitted?

Comment: It may be useful to see your VB.Net code on calling SPs and threading.. Are you using things like EF or Linq to Sql..

Comment: @numbtongue - yes, the service uses EF for interaction with the DB. I've updated the original question with some reduced / modified code that hopefully explains the logic flow?

Comment: Can you try running it without calling WriteTextOutput, to see if this was creating race conditions on the filesystem..

Comment: @numbtongue if I didn't call WriteTextOutput, there'd be no file to import to the staging table? Also, each batch gets its own independent file with a unique filename which includes both the batch ID and a timestamp to millisecond resolution, so there's no possible conflict on the filesystem. Just to clarify, if I take the ProcessBatch function out of the thread and then run it sequentially in the service instead (once all the threads have completed, for each prepared batch), everything runs absolutely fine?

Comment: You could be overwriting one update with another without selecting most.recent set of values..

Comment: Each thread specifically targets only the records in the staging table which belong to its batch ID. No two threads can focus on the same batch ID and each thread fires its updates sequentially. So the only way I can see a conflict would be if a particular thread starts an update before the previous update on the same thread has completed. And given that it waits for a response from the DB before proceeding each time, I don't see how that's possible? Unless it's some quirk of threading in VB.NET that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I think it’s better to have that table loaded into dataset and update locally then commit entire table to dB..

Comment: @AlanO'Brien - Minimal doesn't mean less than necessary. It also doesn't mean a small amount of code. It means the amount - no matter how much - that is necessary to reproduce the issue. The lack of answers is a direct consequence of not having a [mcve].